# Delimited String Space issue bat file

Tags: windows, cmd

```
@echo off

set servers=hello@how@are dd @you
set servers=%servers:@=,%

for %%i in (%servers%) do (
  echo %%i
)
pause
```

This outputs :
hello
how
are
dd
you

But I want :
hello 
how
are dd
you

Any Help Would be great.
Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might solve that issue:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set lf=^


:: leave the two blank lines above

set servers=hello@how@are dd @you
set servers=%servers:@=!lf!%
echo !servers!
pause
```